# Function with parameter called from object

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I'm trying some different things.
Take this following example:

```
function obj(){
    this.execute = function(codeToExecute){
        codeToExecute();
    }
}

// Object init and function call

var obj = obj();
obj.execute(function(){
    alert("G'Day!");
}
```

This will execute the `alert` message. All good until now but now I'm trying to `alert` a message transmitted through a parameter:

```
var obj = obj();
obj.execute(function(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

What should be the structure of the `function obj()` now that I have to insert that parameter somewhere?

I couldn't find anything useful on google because honestly I don't know exactly what I should be looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend `execute` so that any additional parameters are passed to the supplied function:

```
function Obj() {
    this.execute = function(f) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
        f.apply(this, args);
    }
}

var obj = new Obj();
obj.execute(function(message){
    alert(message);
}, "boo!");
```

This line is the "magic" one:

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

It uses the `Array.prototype.slice` function which is used to copy arrays, but (kind of) tricks the function into using the `arguments` pseudo-array as the source array (instead of the supplied `[]`), copying all of the elements apart from the first.

You can't just use `arguments.slice(1)` because `arguments` isn't a *real* JS array.  It has a `.length` property, and you can access `arguments[n]`, but it doesn't have all of the extra functions in its `prototype` that a real array has.  It's close enough though that the implementation of `.slice()` doesn't know any better.

NB: you should use `new` to create an object instance - in your original code you're just *calling* `obj()` immediately and then reassigning the (undefined) result back to `obj` - that code could never have worked at all.

Comment: +1 though the OP might need an example of how to call it from his code :)

Comment: Deleted  my answer. This is the answer.

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you! It works. Could you please explain `[].slice.call(arguments, 1)`? I found some details about `call()` and `apply()` but nothing about `[]`. Thanks again!.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
function obj(){
 this.execute = function(codeToExecute, arg){
     codeToExecute(arg);
   }
} 

var obj = new Obj(); 
obj.execute(function(message){
               alert(message);},
           "yourmessage");
```

Essentially, you pass 2 arguments to your obj.execute:  the function, and the argument to that function.

Comment: For someone new to JavaScript, this might be a little easier to understand.  Using apply and using [] to get the argument array is a little more advanced, even though it is more general purpose.

Comment: Someone new to js should not get into these bad habits. Make maintenance difficult

Answer (score 1):

You could use the good old set/get methods. Below I'm passing in the message into the object constructor and it can be accessed with the `getMessage` function. You can include a set function if you don't want to pass into the constructor

```
function Obj(message){
this.getMessage = function(){
return message;
}
    this.execute = function(codeToExecute){
        codeToExecute();
    }
}

var obj = new Obj("hello");
obj.execute(function(){
    alert(obj.getMessage());
});
```

Comment: that's _really_ horrible.  It makes the function being passed unnecessarily dependent on `Obj`.